# Can an .appex type extension be added to the list of apps with write access?

Tags: applications, security

Background: I have a printer/scanner combo (Brother DCP-9022CDW) which has been orphaned by Brother since MacOS 10.15. Scanning now hangs at the point when the finished file should be written to the connected computer and I strongly suspect that the excessive write access restrictions in the most recent version of MacOS 13.3 are to blame.

Now you can manually add apps in System preferences to give them write access. However, when I try to do so with the system extension which runs the scanner in `/System/Library/ExtensionKit/Extensions/PrinterScannerSettings.appex`, selecting this is not possible. Even selecting the Public folder for the scanner to write into does not help.

I know I can use the old Brother iPrint&Scan app to scan, but my question is about giving write access to a type .appex extension since using Brother iPrint&Scan is rather cumbersome.